# Comparing content with file in Java

Tags: java, string, file, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm trying to take a word as input and check whether that word is present in a text file. But I ended up with this error.

```
import java.io.*;
public class SpellingChecker {
    public static void test(String str) throws IOException{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("wordsEn.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        int i=0,j=0,n=str.length();
        str+=' ';
        String temp="",temp2="";
        do{
            for(i=j;str.charAt(i)!=' ';i++)
                temp+=str.charAt(i);
            System.out.println(temp);
            while((temp2=br.readLine()) != null) {      
                if(temp==temp2) 
                    System.out.print("\t\t\tOK");
                else
                    System.out.print("\t\t\tWRONG");
            }
            temp="";
            j=i+1;
        }while(i<n);
        fr.close();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter string for which you want to check spelling : ");
        String strng=input.nextLine();
        test(strng);
    }
}
```

Error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: wordsEn.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:87)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at SpellingChecker.test(SpellingChecker.java:5)
    at SpellingChecker.main(SpellingChecker.java:29)
```

Comment: Are you sure the path you provided in the FileReader is correct?

Comment: I put the file in the same path as the .java file

Comment: Try using an absolute path to your file (i.e `/path/to/my/wordsEn.txt`)

Comment: And, if you are on `Windows` make sure the file format is what you think it is.

Comment: gives error
    - Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )

Comment: You cannot use backslashes in your path. You have to use forward slashes or escape the backslashes by `\\`.

Comment: Forward slashes did the trick. But its not checking the file properly. Everything shows Output WRONG. Can somebody help me in correcting the logic cuz I don't find a place where I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: when you just give path name it only check in the folder where your class file is. Therefore give relative or absolute path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the name of the file will not do.You have to mention the path of the file while creating
the "FileReader" object.For example,if the path is "C:\wordsEn.txt",you should write:-

```
FileReader fr=new FileReader(new File("C://wordsEn.txt"));
```

Remember,if you use '\' in place of "//" "Illegal Escape Character" will be the error shown.
This should fix it.Give it a try...

Comment: Filename will work if it resides in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your text file in the source directory.

Comment: Actually I'm working in Eclipse, and its in the source directory named as "src" in Eclipse. Atleast that's what I know of.

Comment: Put it in "src/nameOfYourProject"

Comment: Actually its the reverse you just said about- nameOfYourProject/src. I guess thats just a typo. BTW I did put it in that directory.